# Pytorch: use pretrained vectors to initialize nn.Embedding, but this embedding layer is not updated during the training

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I initialized nn.Embedding with some pretrain parameters (they are 128 dim vectors), the following code demonstrates how I do this:

```
self.myvectors = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(cfg.vec_dir)
self.vec_weights = torch.FloatTensor(self.myvectors.vectors)
self.embeds = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(self.vec_weights)
```

cfg.vec_dir is a json file where vec_dir indicates the path of the pretrained 128 dim vectors I used to initialize this layer.

After the model is trained, I print out this embedding layer, and I found that the parameters are exactly the same as I initialized them, so clearly the parameters are not updated during the training. Why is this happening? What should I do in order to update these vectors?

Answer (score 2):

The `torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained` classmethod by default freezes the parameters. If you want to train the parameters, you need to set the `freeze` keyword argument to `False`. See [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html#torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained).

So you might try this instead:

```
self.embeds = torch.nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(self.vec_weights, freeze=False)
```